# Look up for two values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

[image]

I Have data set which contains Duration and Code with subject wise material observed. Which formula i have to use to get the value of total for month=june & Code=BHEB. I have tried using two dimension look up formula.

```
=INDEX(DataRange, MATCH(Code,Code,0), MATCH(Durations,Duration,0))
```

it doesn't suit my suitation, i cant change month value to column.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Take two inputs `code` and `duration` and get it to return the total value? Is this on the same sheet or another sheet?

Comment: @AlexP : Different Sheets

Comment: @pnuts: Oh yes.. I used it earlier.. Thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a helper column (may be hidden), say inserted as A in the image, populated with:

```
=B1&"|"&C1
```

and copied down to suit then:

```
=INDEX(DataRange, MATCH(Code&"|"&Semester,A:A,0), MATCH(Durations,Duration,0))
```

may serve where the named ranges are:

DataRange : =Sheet!$C$1:$G$5
Code : =Sheet!$J$1
Semester : =Sheet!$J$2
Durations : =Sheet!$J$3
Duration : =Sheet!$C$1:$G$1

or extended to suit.

[image: SO24333757 example]